# How can I convert a flax.linen.Module to a torch.nn.Module?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, flax

I would like to convert a `flax.linen.Module`, taken from [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SeXMpILhkJPjXUaesvzEhc3Ke6Zl_zxJ?usp=sharing) and replicated below this post, to a `torch.nn.Module`.

However, I find it extremely hard to figure out how I need to replace

1. The `flax.linen.Dense` calls;
2. The `flax.linen.Conv` calls;
3. The custom class `Dense`.

For (1.), I guess I need to use `torch.nn.Linear`. But what do I need to specify as `in_features` and `out_features`?

For (2.), I guess I need to use `torch.nn.Conv2d`. But, again, what do I need to specify as `in_channels` and `out_channels`.

I guess I know how I can port the `GaussianFourierProjection` class and how I can mimic the "swish activation function". Obviously, it would be extremely helpful if someone is that familiar with both modules so that he/she can provide the corresponding `torch.nn.Module` as an answer. But it would also already be helpful, if someone could at least answer how (1.) - (3.) need to be replaced. Any help is highly appreciated!

---

```
#@title Defining a time-dependent score-based model (double click to expand or collapse)

import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np
import flax
import flax.linen as nn
from typing import Any, Tuple
import functools
import jax

class GaussianFourierProjection(nn.Module):
  """Gaussian random features for encoding time steps."""  
  embed_dim: int
  scale: float = 30.
  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, x):    
    # Randomly sample weights during initialization. These weights are fixed 
    # during optimization and are not trainable.
    W = self.param('W', jax.nn.initializers.normal(stddev=self.scale), 
                 (self.embed_dim // 2, ))
    W = jax.lax.stop_gradient(W)
    x_proj = x[:, None] * W[None, :] * 2 * jnp.pi
    return jnp.concatenate([jnp.sin(x_proj), jnp.cos(x_proj)], axis=-1)


class Dense(nn.Module):
  """A fully connected layer that reshapes outputs to feature maps."""  
  output_dim: int  
  
  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, x):
    return nn.Dense(self.output_dim)(x)[:, None, None, :]    


class ScoreNet(nn.Module):
  """A time-dependent score-based model built upon U-Net architecture.
  
  Args:
      marginal_prob_std: A function that takes time t and gives the standard
        deviation of the perturbation kernel p_{0t}(x(t) | x(0)).
      channels: The number of channels for feature maps of each resolution.
      embed_dim: The dimensionality of Gaussian random feature embeddings.
  """
  marginal_prob_std: Any
  channels: Tuple[int] = (32, 64, 128, 256)
  embed_dim: int = 256
  
  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, x, t): 
    # The swish activation function
    act = nn.swish
    # Obtain the Gaussian random feature embedding for t   
    embed = act(nn.Dense(self.embed_dim)(
        GaussianFourierProjection(embed_dim=self.embed_dim)(t)))
        
    # Encoding path
    h1 = nn.Conv(self.channels[0], (3, 3), (1, 1), padding='VALID',
                   use_bias=False)(x)    
    ## Incorporate information from t
    h1 += Dense(self.channels[0])(embed)
    ## Group normalization
    h1 = nn.GroupNorm(4)(h1)    
    h1 = act(h1)
    h2 = nn.Conv(self.channels[1], (3, 3), (2, 2), padding='VALID',
                   use_bias=False)(h1)
    h2 += Dense(self.channels[1])(embed)
    h2 = nn.GroupNorm()(h2)        
    h2 = act(h2)
    h3 = nn.Conv(self.channels[2], (3, 3), (2, 2), padding='VALID',
                   use_bias=False)(h2)
    h3 += Dense(self.channels[2])(embed)
    h3 = nn.GroupNorm()(h3)
    h3 = act(h3)
    h4 = nn.Conv(self.channels[3], (3, 3), (2, 2), padding='VALID',
                   use_bias=False)(h3)
    h4 += Dense(self.channels[3])(embed)
    h4 = nn.GroupNorm()(h4)    
    h4 = act(h4)

    # Decoding path
    h = nn.Conv(self.channels[2], (3, 3), (1, 1), padding=((2, 2), (2, 2)),
                  input_dilation=(2, 2), use_bias=False)(h4)    
    ## Skip connection from the encoding path
    h += Dense(self.channels[2])(embed)
    h = nn.GroupNorm()(h)
    h = act(h)
    h = nn.Conv(self.channels[1], (3, 3), (1, 1), padding=((2, 3), (2, 3)),
                  input_dilation=(2, 2), use_bias=False)(
                      jnp.concatenate([h, h3], axis=-1)
                  )
    h += Dense(self.channels[1])(embed)
    h = nn.GroupNorm()(h)
    h = act(h)
    h = nn.Conv(self.channels[0], (3, 3), (1, 1), padding=((2, 3), (2, 3)),
                  input_dilation=(2, 2), use_bias=False)(
                      jnp.concatenate([h, h2], axis=-1)
                  )    
    h += Dense(self.channels[0])(embed)    
    h = nn.GroupNorm()(h)  
    h = act(h)
    h = nn.Conv(1, (3, 3), (1, 1), padding=((2, 2), (2, 2)))(
        jnp.concatenate([h, h1], axis=-1)
    )

    # Normalize output
    h = h / self.marginal_prob_std(t)[:, None, None, None]
    return h
```